# HDRi backgrounds refuse to display on certain Blend files

Tags: hdri, world

I'm suddenly running into an issue where certain Blend files will not display an HDRi in the viewport or render. Objects behave as though they're receiving light from the HDRi, but the HDRi background itself is a no show. If there is a setting for this, I can't find it. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.3.0., Windows 11

[image]

[blend](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/hdri_noshow.blend)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fixed checker background is indicative of a transparent background display. This happens when you enable the transparency of your background.

You can undo this by unchecking the option in the *Properties Editor* > *Render*  tab > *Film* panel > *Transparent* option:

[image: panel]